# Mathematica undocumented Dynamic solution needed

Tags: variables, dynamic, wolfram-mathematica, slider

I'm trying to have a slider update a derivative value for 2 Polynomial curves and return that dynamically to a variable to be used outside of dynamic.  I get the slider to move and the value for the combined lines for the full range of x, but not the returned value to be used outside of the dynamic slider.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

```
cyL= 58.770000000000046` - 3.557000000000158` x - 
   3.525333333333144` x^2 + 4.987999999999908` x^3 - 
   1.3386666666666487` x^4;

cyA[y_] := -35.13365403304179` - 0.009572400388682331` x + 
   0.08989310009715228` x^2 - 0.01687074829931251` x^3;

change= -0.17006802721089645` + 62.92517006802724` x - 
   6.802721088435384` x^2;
```

The part below produces sliders that display the proper values in the first slider, but not the second.

```
Column[{Slider[Dynamic[x, Automatic]], Dynamic[cyL /. x -> change]},
{Slider[Dynamic[g, Automatic]], Dynamic[cyA /. y -> change]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! @R Hall - I would suggest asking this over on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com. You'll get a quicker response. Also, you can format code by clicking on the '{}' image in the text editor when you have your code highlighted. It'll make things easier to read!

Comment: Couple errors in syntax: your polynomial `cyA[y]` doesn't have any `y` in the function itself. Then, you call `cyA` which won't do anything because you've defined `cyA[y]`. Finally, your `Column` statement needs another `{}` pair around the inside list.

Comment: Thank you!  I'l do that in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure that I understand what you want to do with the `change` variable, but here is a version that works with both sliders updating their respective functions:

```
cyL[x_] := 
  58.770000000000046` - 3.557000000000158` x - 
   3.525333333333144` x^2 + 4.987999999999908` x^3 - 
   1.3386666666666487` x^4;

cyA[y_] := -35.13365403304179` - 0.009572400388682331` y + 
   0.08989310009715228` y^2 - 0.01687074829931251` y^3;

change[x_] := -0.17006802721089645` + 62.92517006802724` x - 
   6.802721088435384` x^2;

Column[{{Slider[Dynamic[x, Automatic]], 
   Dynamic[cyL[change[x]]]}, {Slider[Dynamic[g, Automatic]], 
   Dynamic[cyA[change[g]]]}}]
```

Comment: Thanks tkott, but the values returned by x, and g are just slider positions and not the derived value from the lines.

Comment: Well, in either case, the example above works. There are some problems with your syntax with Column, and also your cyA. Then you need to make sure that your functions are correct, and perhaps explain more clearly what you are trying to do. You can use latex code (within $) to display the original equations. I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: From R Hall: "What did get posted was incorrect. What I had actually said and was not included in that post was that the aim of this function is to get the value of x for both change and cyL and change and cya, So for the slider at position zero, the value returned for x is the first value out of the function at the value derived from change[x] What returns for x here is the slider position and not the displayed value for the function. How do I get the sliders to populate x with the result of f[x] for the combination of these lines? Thanks for your help and patience!"